# Parse Cloud Code: how to sort by geo distance when key is in pointer

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

My use-case is sort list by a distance. I have `Promo` class, which is many-to-one with `Vendor` class. I insert `vendor` key in `Promo` class. I use `.near`, and set key `vendor.geo`. But I get an error. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but please guide me the correct way. Thanks.

```
const promoQuery = new Parse.Query('Promo')
  .include('photo')
  .include('vendor')
  .include('vendor.name')
  .exists('vendor')
  .lessThanOrEqualTo('startDate', currentDate)
  .greaterThanOrEqualTo('endDate', currentDate)
  .near('vendor.geo', new Parse.GeoPoint(currentGeo)) // this cause an error
  .descending('createdAt')
```

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to solve this? I'm facing the same issue ! grr !